# SESSION varibales are not displayed after redirection used with memcache

Tags: session, memcached, php

I have a page session_config.php in that page I have following code

```php
session_name('session_sw');
session_start();
$session_ID = session_id();
```

I have another page index.php in which I am including session_config.php ,the code as follows.

```php
$email = $_REQUEST['email'];
$pass = $_REQUEST['pass'];
$error = 0;
if(!empty($email) && !empty($pass)) {
 $url = "$SERVER/sw/apis/3rdpartylogin.php?advertiser_login=1&pass=$pass&email=$email";
 $resp = file_get_contents($url);// it sends json encoded string.
 $resp = json_decode($resp);
 if ( $resp->status == 'success' ) {

    if ( !isset($resp->mesg->profile) || $resp->mesg->profile == 0 ){
        $error = '1';
    } else {

        include "session_config.php";
        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $resp->mesg->user_id;
        $_SESSION['customer_id'] = $resp->mesg->customer_id;
        $_SESSION['customer_name'] = $resp->mesg->customer_name;
        $_SESSION['logged_in_user_email'] = $_REQUEST['email'];
        $_SESSION['agency_name'] = $resp->mesg->agency_name;
        $_SESSION['profile'] = $resp->mesg->profile;
        $_SESSION['metadata'] = $resp->mesg->metadata;
        $_SESSION['show_archival'] = $resp->mesg->show_archival;
        $_SESSION['show_live'] = $resp->mesg->show_live;
        $_SESSION['show_sov'] = $resp->mesg->show_sov;
        $_SESSION[$session_ID]['session_name'] = 'surewaves_agency_view';

        header("Location: reach.php");exit;
    }
} else {
    $error = '1';
}
}
?>
```

// Here I am able fetch the correct data in '$resp' variable and also it is redirecting to reach.php
In reach.php , i have following code

```php
<?php
    include "session_config.php";
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($_SESSION);exit;
?>
```

But in reach.php when I am fetching the session variables  the session array is showing completely empty like this Array (). WHY?
I am using memcache for it and we are using ubuntu.
In My php.ini i have included following code..

```ini
extension = memcache.so;
session.save_handler = memcache
session.save_path = "http://localhost:11211"
```

I have also tried with "tcp ://localhost:11211" but nothing worked.

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove the `http://` part from session.save_path and replace `localhost` with `127.0.0.1`:

```
session.save_path = "127.0.0.1:11211"
```

Take a look at the second example at https://www.php.net/manual/en/memcache.examples-overview.php.